# Javascript not running on Heroku, dev fine, others fine

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a Rails 3.1 app with several Javascripts that run just fine on Heroku. I wanted to auto detect time zones and started working with this Jon Nylanders awesome script to do that. It's available here: https://bitbucket.org/pellepim/jstimezonedetect/src

Now the problem is, this Javascript runs just fine on my local machine but not on Heroku. The console in Safari says the function is undefined. I call it like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var tz = jstz.determine();
</script>
```

The main difference between this Javascript and the others I use is that this one has a name space. Maybe that has something to do with it?

I have run rake and I have verified that application.js contains the script. I have tried the downloadable minified version as well as the full source in it's own .js file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there was an error in another Javascript, an error that I disregarded for the time being (as I didn't use that code anyway). When compiled into application.js however, this error somehow disturbed the execution of all the other javascripts too.

Comment: Generally when there's an error in processing a `<script>` block, the processing is completely aborted.